# jQuery UI Tabs not hiding inactive tabs on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm having a strange problem with jQuery tabs. The tabs are working fine, but the inactive panels are remaining visible on load, and it's only when selecting other tabs that they are hidden.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict(); 
(function($) {
    $(function() {  
        /* UI Tabs */
        $.fn.tabs && $(".tabs").tabs();
    });
}) (jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I've not seen this before. Can anyone spot anything I might have missed?

Cheers,
RJ

Comment: Are you using the correct version of jQueryui.css for jqueryui.js?

Comment: Yes, definately. It's strange because it's working fine in the local files, but on the server it decides to keep the panels shown on load.

Comment: try refreshing all cache in both environments, does that affect either?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've had to settle with adding style="display:none;" manually to all but the first tab. Very irritating issue. It works fine on jsfiddle too. I'm guessing there is some clash with another plugin/framework, but with no errors narrowing that down could take forever.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the display: none is what I had to do as well. Wordpress.

Answer (score 3):

Bit crude as it doesn't address the root of the problem but it sure solved it; i simply added the following to my stylesheet.

```
    <style>
        .ui-tabs-hide { display: none; }
    </style>`
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Yup. It sure helped. In my case, just adding the above code didn't fix it (cause the display:none was being overwritten by a display:block from the .ui-tabs class - so, i just had to put a !important right after the display:none from your suggestion). Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem. Try adding this exact chuck in your style sheet.

```
div .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
display: none;
}
```

For some reason I keep getting a style...

```
div {display: block;}
```

...that kept overriding my .ui-tabs-hide fix that Ronald provided.

Hope this helps,

Rock

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.ui-tabs-hide { 
    display: none !important; 
 }
```

The *!important* assures that nothing else will override this.

Comment: This is the last resort, edge case solution. It's almost always better to use a more specific selector to override a previous style.